# How to log "n" numbers along with their corresponding time? Beginner task

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please bear with me, my question isn't as daunting as it looks. Everything is perfect and working until the 4th section.

```
def readTemperature():
"""It will read the string, extract the temperature, then return the data
as a float.
"""
data = readTemperatureSensor.randomTemperatureGenerator()
data = str(data)
for line in data:
    if "t" in line:
        tempBit = data.split("t")
        tempString = tempBit[1].replace("=", "")
return float(tempString)/1000
```

The above code just reads a temperature.

```
def getTemperatures(n):
"""Returns a list of floats that contain a certain number (n) of
temperature readings that have been sampled at an interval of one second.
"""
temperaturelist = []
for data in range(n):
    temperaturelist.append(float(readTemperature()))
    time.sleep(1)
return temperaturelist
```

The above code gets a bunch of temperatures that have been measured a second apart.

```
def getTimeStamp():
    """Returns the current system date and time as a string with the format
    YYYY_MM_DD_HH_MM_SS.
    """
    return time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S")
```

Just a simple time stamp.

Now, the part I don't know what to do.

```
def logTemperatures(n):
"""This function will record "n" temperature readings and their
corresponding time-stamps, sampled at 1 seconds intervals.
"""
```

Basically, it wants me to create a text file (which I can do), but also wants me to read "n" temperatures and have it's corresponding time as well. If it were simply logging a set amount of temperatures, then I could do it and my code would look like this:

```
f = open('logTemperatures.txt', 'w')
type(f)
myList = getTemperatures(3)
currentTime = time.time()
f.write(str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S",
                          time.localtime(currentTime - 0.03 * 60))))
f.write(',')
f.write(" ")
f.write(str(myList[0]))
f.write('\n')
f.write(str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S",
                          time.localtime(currentTime - 0.02 * 60))))
f.write(',')
f.write(" ")
f.write(str(myList[1]))
f.write('\n')
f.write(str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S",
                          time.localtime(currentTime - 0.01 * 60))))
f.write(',')
f.write(" ")
f.write(str(myList[2]))
f.close()

logTemperatures(3)
```

There's lots of f.write functions because I'm still a beginner, but I know now that I can use the + button to link it all up.

The text file would look like this:

---

Time, Temperature 1

Time + 1 second, Temperature 2

Time + 2 seconds, Temperature 3

---

And it could be up to 10 temperatures or just 1. Obviously, the above code wouldn't work since it will only ever do it for 3 temperatures and not "n" temperatures. How can I modify it so that it will do it for "n" temperatures?

Comment: use a for loop like you did in `getTemperatures(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that takes in a list of temperatures and iterates over each item in the list, creating an entry for it in the log file.

```
def logTemps(tempList):
    with open('logTemperatures.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        currentTime = time.time()
        for i, temp in enumerate(tempList):
            outfile.write(str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S", 
                              time.localtime(currentTime - 60 * (0.01 * (len(tempList) - i))))))
            outfile.write(', ' + str(temp) + '\n')
```

You'd call the method by inputting your `myList` from the previous example to the function:

```
logTemps(myList)
```

Couple of things to mention that I did:

Use `with open('example.txt', 'w') as yourVariableNameHere` blocks instead of `open()` and `close()`. `with` blocks with files automatically closes the file at the end of the block and it clearly indicates to anyone reading the code what you're doing.

I did `0.01*the length of the list - the current index`, but I hope you realize that that means you will end up with `currentTime - 3, currentTime - 2, and currentTime - 1`...not `currentTime, currentTime + 1, currentTime + 2` which you seem to think.

Also there's really no reason to separate those writes on different lines so I just combined them to one `outfile.write('...')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! It took a bit of time for me to wrap my head around what you had written, sorry. With your "for i, temp in enumerate(tempList)" line though, I receive an "int is not iterable" error. I've only ever used range(), so I don't understand what's wrong with your script.

Comment: @Scarthia is the tempList you're providing it a list of temperatures? Or is it just one integer? it needs to be a list e.g. in the format of `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. Also, are you sure you actually wrote  the `enumerate`? Because if not it will give you that error.

Comment: All of them contain decimal places, so none of them are whole numbers. I changed the tempList to getTemperatures (second part) since that's what I was working with and it does return it as a list inside the square brackets as you showed. Thank you very much for your help again! :)

Answer (score -3):

In python 3

```
n = input("Enter the number: ")
```

Then:

```
myList = getTemperatures(n)
currentTime = time.time()

for data in myList:
    f.write(str(time.strftime("%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S",
                      time.localtime(currentTime - 0.02 * 60))))
    f.write(',')
    f.write(" ")
    f.write(str(data))
    f.write('\n')

f.close()
logTemperatures(n)
```